# Heroku CloudFlare No Such App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns, cname, cloudflare

I read these 2 articles

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/set-up-cloudflare-free-ssl-on-heroku
http://www.higherorderheroku.com/articles/cloudflare-dns-heroku/

And trying to use Cloudflare with Heroku:

I have set the 2 CNAME as indicated:

www -> myherokudomain.herokuapp.com

mydomain.com -> myherokudomain.herokuapp.com

And set the DNS accordingly, which work correctly with cloudflare

```
curl -I mydomain.com                                   
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Server: cloudflare-nginx
```

But I am still getting a "Heroku no such app".

Anyone having the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your heroku app needs to have the custom domain addon for this to work.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like something is not configured properly at Heroku, so I would check with them. The record is returning a 404.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my app hosted on Heroku.

For me, accessing my app via [www.myowndomain.com](http://www.myowndomain.com) works.
However, accessing the app directly via the root domain (myowndomain.com) displays a "No Such App" on the heroku platform.

doing a ping on Terminal reveals that:

`curl -I www.myowndomain.com` (works correctly), while;
`curl -I myowndomain.com` (doesn't work)

So, I added another custom domain name on heroku using 'myowndomain.com' as opposed to the first custom domain 'www.myowndomain.com' which I earlier added.

I copied the target and created a new CNAME record on my Cloudflare account.
Cloudflare immediately applied [CNAME flattening.](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-cname-flattening-rfc-compliant-cnames-at-a-domains-root/)

Now, my app can be accessed both via: [www.myowndomain.com](http://www.myowndomain.com)
and directly, via: myowndomain.com