# Heroku and Cloudflare integration "No such app"

Tags: heroku

I have a bit of a hard time getting Heroku and Cloudflare connected. The only other question I could find was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332383/heroku-cloudflare-no-such-app), and it was not particularly helpful since I already created a custom domain entry.

What I did:

- Added a custom domain:
  [image: Custom domain added to Heroku]
- Configured the domain like this in Cloudflare, which I believe is correct:
  [image: Cloudflare config]

But when I visit my custom domain, I get the
[image: Heroku error page]

When I visit my .herokuapp.com subdomain, I see:
[image: How it is supposed to look]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The page now magically works, and I have no idea why since I wrote the post when the had been added for over 48 hours.